# How to prevent change detection on scroll? ( Angular )

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a large component, and I would like to avoid unnecessary change detections to increase performance.

I added `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the `@Component`.

I would like to update the style of an element if it is scrolled. Unfortunately Angular runs the change detection, every time I scroll that element.

I tried to add an event listener to the native element to avoid this, but the change detection is still running again when I scroll:

```
@ViewChild('my_element') my_element_ref: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.my_element_ref.nativeElement.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateStyle);
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('check');
}
```

The `ngAfterViewChecked` is called even if `this.updateStyle` is an empty function.
But if I comment out `this.my_element_ref.nativeElement.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)`, then `ngAfterViewChecked` is not called anymore.

How is it possible to call a function when an element is scrolled, but avoid Angular's change detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use ngZone.runOutsideAngular.

```
constructor (private zone : NgZone) {}
ngAfterViewInit () : any {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=> {
        console.log( 'scroll event fired' );
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at ChangeDetectorRef API. 
Specifically you would detach the change detection for the component using detach() (maybe in the constructor like below) and then mark component for change in your scroll function via markForCheck().

```js
  constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cd.detach();
  }
```

```js
this.cd.markForCheck();
```

Below links for your reference.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 1):

just inject `NgZone` in your constructor and then subscribe to an event like this:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  ....addEventListener('...);
});
```

keep in mind that change detection will not be called in this case, so you won't be able to change styles with template binding. It should be changed by native javascript or using `Renderer2`